# Concurrently writing to file while reading it out using mmap

Tags: c++, multithreading, file-io, mmap

The situation is this.

1. A large buffer of data (which shall exceed reasonable RAM
   consumption) is being generated by the program.
2. The program concurrently serves a websocket which will allow a web
   client to specify a small subset of this buffer of data to view.

To support the first goal, the file is written to using standard methods (I use portable C-stdio `fopen` and `fwrite` because it's been shown to be faster than various "pure C++" methods. Doesn't matter. Data gets appended to file; stdio will buffer the writes and periodically flush them.)

To support the second goal (on BSD, in particular iOS), the file is opened (`open` from `sys/fcntl.h` -- *not* as portable as `stdio.h`) and memory-mapped (`mmap` from `sys/mman.h` -- ditto). By deciding to use memory mapping I have to give up some portability with this code. It seems like Boost is something I could look at to avoid wheel reinvention.

Anyway, my question is about how exactly I'm supposed to do this, because there will be at least two threads: The main program thread appending to the file periodically, and the network (or a worker) thread which responds to web requests and delivers data read out of the memory regions that are mapped to the file on disk.

Supposing the file starts out 1024 bytes in size, `mmap` is called initially mapping 1024 bytes. As the main thread writes a further 512 bytes into the file, how can the network thread be notified or know anything about the current actual size of the file (so that it can `munmap` and `mmap` again with a larger buffer corresponding to the new size)? Furthermore, if I do this naively, I am wary of a situation where the main thread reports that 512 bytes are written, so the other thread now maps 1536 bytes of the file, but not all of the new 512 bytes actually got written to disk yet (OS is still working on writing it, maybe). What happens now? Could there be some garbage that shows up? Will my program crash?

How can I determine when data has been properly flushed? How can I be notified in a timely fashion after the data has been flushed so that I can memory map it?

In particular, is calling `fflush` the only way to guarantee that the file is now updated w.r.t. the stream, and then can I guarantee (once `fflush` returns) that the memory map can access the new size without an access violation? What about `fsync`?

Comment: For what I'm working on at the moment, it is more important not to slow the process down (with extra `fflush`/`fsync`), so I am thinking now that perhaps the most suitable method is to open the file anew periodically (read-only of course) to `fseek` and `ftell` to check its length.

Answer (score 1):

When you are using POSIX API directly in the form of `mmap`, you should also be using it directly for the writing. POSIX and LibC interfaces just don't play well together.

`write` is a system call which transfers the data directly to kernel. It would be slow for writing byte-by-byte, but for writing large buffers it is tiny fraction faster because it has less overhead (`fwrite` ends up calling `write` under the hood anyway). And it is definitely more efficient that `fwrite`+`fflush`, because those may end up being two or more calls to `write` and if you do direct `write`, it is just one.

The documentation of [mmap](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/mmap.html) is not very clear about it, but it seems you must not request more bytes than the file actually has.

Comment: So how then can I append to a file? I was pretty sure you can't use `mmap` to append to a file (make it bigger than it already is). But I would love to be proven wrong about that. There's nothing that makes it so I can't also use `mmap` to do the appending, it's just that I don't think there's a way to do it. And it just seems like you're telling me to "just use `write`"... which... probably could work too but I just figured it would be a lot more complicated than using the c std lib.

Comment: Ah, sorry. You are simply saying use `write` since that's also POSIX API.

Comment: @StevenLu: Yes, I am simply saying that it will be easier when you use POSIX API, `write`, for writing as well, because it is lower level and so the interaction with `mmap` will be more obvious.. `mmap` can't be used for appending; if I read the documentation right (which I am not completely sure) it will fail if you try passing bigger `len` than the current size of the file.

Comment: Well I still don't know if this answers the fundamental question of how can I synchronize my concurrent memory-mapped reads so as to ensure I don't seg-fault... How do I know that once I call `write` that my subsequent access (via mmapped memory from a different thread, no less) to that data (that has just been passed over to the kernel) will not be an access violation?

Comment: It is because of this uncertainty (and a similar uncertainties if I just pick some size to back off from) that I think I'll just resort to independently opening and checking the length of the file using the cstdio method, and do this periodically from the thread that calls mmap. That should guarantee that I never attempt to read past the boundary.

Comment: @JanHudec, that's correct. You have to use `mremap()` when you enlarge the file which you can do with a `write()` or `truncate()`. You have to be careful if you `truncate()` the file to a smaller size, though.